# “Combover” — is there a German equivalent?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

A student of mine asked me how a German might say *combover*. It's that interesting hair style when someone is bald, but they have hair on one side of their head, and comb it over to the other side. It blows away in the wind.

I usually pride myself on my knowledge of bizarre and varied German vocab, but I couldn’t help him on this occasion.

I’ve asked a couple of my German friends, who say there’s no such expression … Can anyone out there help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Anything you want to know about how this site works can be found in the [help] =)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Frisuren) doesn’t list a German translation or name. I’m pretty sure I’ve heard a semi-intuitive, semi-humorous compound with _Scheitel_ or _Glatze_ being used for this hairstyle before, but can’t remember it. There certainly isn’t a word as established as _combover_ in English which is also used in German as a loan word.

Comment: If I were to invent a word for it, I’d probably choose one of _Naturfifi, Naturtoupet, Naturperücke, Eigenfifi, Eigentoupet, Eigenperücke, Eigenhaarfifi, Eigenhaartoupet, Eigenhaarperücke_, but all could be understood to mean a wig made of natural (instead of artificial) hair, especially one’s own (e.g. made before chemotherapy).

Comment: I have heard "Fleischmütze" for for being bald, and "Klappscheitel" for someone trying to hide bald spots by combing rest hair to the side. Both obviously don't fit here.

Comment: There was an Ally McBeal episode centering on a client being sued for fraud because he wore a combover. The German dubbing rendered this as "überkämmte Glatze", so apparently they didn't know a single-word solution either.

Comment: [Relevant](http://trumpdonald.org/)

Comment: I started mysearch at the most extreme famous case of a comb-over: The classic "Happiness is a cigar called Hamlet" spots, was led to the actor Gregor Fisher and his show "The baldy man" - which does have a German Wikipedia entry, in which his hairdo is described as "... besteht lediglich aus einem schmalen, vom rechten zum linken Ohr gekämmten Haarstreifen, der Rest ist kahl - ein sogenannter Comb-Over." Dammit, back to square one ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Überkämmfrisur" scheint mir der passende Begriff zu sein.

Comment: Weißt du was? Mit einer Google-Suche nach dem Wort Überkämmftisur habe ich ein Bild von Donald Trump gefunden. Das könnte der passendste von all den bis jetzt vorgeschlagenen Begriffen sein. Herzlichen Dank.

Comment: Das Wort *»Überkämmfrisur«* habe ich noch nie zuvor gehört, und es steht auch nicht in der [Wortformenliste des Instituts für deutsche Sprache](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html). Dort stehen immerhin alle Wörter bis zur Häufigkeitsklasse 29. Ein Wort in dieser Klasse kommt im Schnitt einmal innerhalb von 40 Milliarden Wörtern vor. (Zum Vergleich: Die Bibel enthält ca 740.000 Wörter.) 40 Mrd sind also 50.000 Bände vom Umfang der Bibel. Und wenn in dieser Textmenge ein Wort wenigstens einmal vorkommt, steht es schon in der genannten Liste.

Comment: Forsts.: Dort steht es aber nicht. Auch der [Ngram-Viewer von Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams) kennt das Wort nicht. Mit anderen Worten: Dieses Wort ist absolut ungebräuchlich im Deutschen. Niemand verwendet es. Es ist zwar eine passende Übersetzung für den englischen Begriff, es ist im Deutschen aber nicht etabliert.

Comment: Nun, wenn man sich die Vorschläge in [diesem Leo-Thread](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewWrongentry.php?idThread=46059) anguckt und sie googelt, ist Überkämmfrisur noch einer der besseren. Wird von Google sogar in einigen Büchern gefunden.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, that you mean the special arrangement of hairs, where a few have to cover a large bald area of the head, I' m only aware of

> Querfrisur

Comment: Die Frage kam, weil der Schüler das Aussehen Donald Trump beschreiben wollte.  Daher kam die Frage - "how do you say "Combover"?".  Darf ich ihm sagen, "Donald Trump hat eine Querfrisur"?

Comment: Ich fürchte, dafür ist es nicht das richtige Wort. [Dieser](http://www.stuttgarter-zeitung.de/inhalt.spott-ueber-trumps-frisur-was-traegt-er-da-auf-dem-kopf.9ad50c17-df99-40f5-bd87-84785d773e76.html) Zeitungsartikel befasst sich damit, behauptet aber, der Zustand der Haarpracht im unbehandelten Zustand sei unklar. *Föhnfrisur* wäre noch ein halbwegs passendes Wort.

Comment: Das Wort habe ich noch nie gehört. Google [findet es](https://www.google.de/search?q=Querfrisur&gbv=1&tbs=li:1&prmd=ivns&filter=0) nur auf vier (!) Seiten (inklusive dieser Frage hier). Ist *Querfrisur* Teil deines Wortschatzes (auch schon mal benutzt?) oder hast du das bei der Recherche für diese Frage gefunden?

Comment: Ich fürchte, ich werde meinem Schüler sagen müssen, es gibt keinen deutschen Begriff dafür. Nicht so schlimm - bei Herrn Trump hat man so viele andere Möglichkeiten, ihn zu beschreiben...

Comment: @unor: Insbesondere zeigt Google Images wider Erwarten für so einen (grafisch darstellbaren) Begriff kein einziges Bild an, das die Bedeutung bestätigt. Ich sehe da nur Pferde sowie junge Damen, die eindeutig weit entfernt von einer Glatze sind.

Comment: @unor Cornelia Funke, Die Geisterjäger: "Die Augen des Professors waren seltsam hell, fast farblos, wie alles an ihm. Selbst seine Haut war blass wie verblichenes Papier, und sein spärliches Haar, quer über den kahlen Kopf gekämmt, hatte die Farbe getrockneten Schlammes." Das ist mir bei dem trivialen Wortbildungsmuster dicht genug dran.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Wenn ich *combover* google sehe ich nur junge Männer mit vielen Haaren, die nach einer seite gekämmt sind. Das ist ja auch nicht gerade was man mit einer Glatze assoziiert. Erst recht weit unten kommen dann die überkämmten Glatzen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde *überkämmte Glatze* vorschlagen. Es gibt auch eine ganze Menge Bilder dazu: [Google images](https://www.google.de/search?q=%C3%BCberk%C3%A4mmte+Glatze&newwindow=1&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhlaaAw4LZAhVMiqQKHbaYC6sQsAQIVA&biw=1920&bih=1030)

Dazu gibt es auch Übersetzungsvorschläge, z.B. *combover*.

Comment: Hier in Schweden nennen wir das "Robin Hood-Frisur", man nimmt ja von den Reichen und gibt zu den Armen. Schlage diesen Namen auch für das Deutsche vor.

Comment: @Beta: LOL! Habe gerade nachgesehen: Wikipedia verweist für comb-over oder combover auf 5 Artikel in anderen Sprachen. In den Niederlanden heißt das auch *overkammen* (comb over).

Answer (score 1):

Strangely there seems to be no substantive for this in use in German. However, this hair style is mentioned plenty of times in fiction, usually in form of

> Er trug die Haare über die Glatze gekämmt

or

> Er trug, was er noch an Haaren hatte, seitlich über die Glatze gekämmt

and so on.